# Synthesis of adenosine diphosphate?

Tags: biochemistry, nucleotide-metabolism

Where does the ADP come from? As in before ADP was made from ATP and visa-versa how is it conceived that they appeared in nature?

Comment: You can't synthesize ADP from just hydrogen; it also requires carbon, oxygen, nitrogen and phosphorous.

Comment: Cool so step 1, carbon oxygen nitrogen and phosphorous are all created through fusion from products up from hydrogen. That star eventually yields iron and explodes, what happens next?

Answer (score 1):

Adenosine diphosphate is a [nucleotide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleotide), specifically a *purine* nucleotide, since it contains a double ring. These nucleotides are synthesized by cells from amino acids and other nutrients in a rather long and complicated biochemical pathway. You can find information about this pathway in any biochemical textbook, or see this page in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purine_metabolism#Biosynthesis).

Comment: Your answer is inadequate because it assumes the preexistence of the product.

Comment: @kpie  No, it doesn't.  The purines are synthesized from simpler building blocks, like amino acids.  I suggest you read up on the biosynthesis pathway.

Comment: ATP -> ADP provides energy at several junctures of the pathways you referenced. like you can't synthesize IMP without ATP, and you can't get credit for answering this question without actually answering it. I'm pretty much looking for someone to layout their theories on life and here you are diminishing the question with your ego.